# Twilio sandbox webhook url returning timeout execution error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

can anyone please tell me how to increase timeout for twilio sandbox http post url.
I am trying to building one programmable chat application using whatsapp twilio sandbox using asp.net technology.
Normally my application methods takes 20 plus seconds to run but when i did same thing on twilio sandbox then its returning execution timeout error.
is there any way to increase timeout for twilio sandbox using .net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The Twilio webhook timeout is 15 seconds and it can't be changed.

Web applications that take 20+ seconds to respond to incoming requests are not recommended in general. They ties up processes and resources on your server and may lead to other requests being dropped.

I would recommend you do whatever work that takes more than 20 seconds in a background worker outside of the main web process. You can then respond to the webhook quickly, with an empty response and then [use the REST API to send your reply message](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/whatsapp/api) once the work is done.